# Django Rest Framework Viewset Filter By Value

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Let's say I have a DRF viewset like so

```py
    class SecretViewset(
        viewsets.ModelViewSet,
    ):
    
        queryset = Secret.objects.all()
        serializer_class = SecretSerializer
    
        @action(methods=['GET'], detail=True)
        def name(self, request, pk=None):
            secrets = Secret.objects.filter(name__contains=pk)
            return Response(self.get_serializer(secrets, many=True).data)
```

I want to be able to search via a name in the URL.  So `/api/secrets/name/NAMEHERE/`

However, because ModelViewset implements `mixins.Retrieve`, it returns a 404 because it searches `/api/secrets/ID/` first and doesn't find it, therefore throws a 404.

What would the proper way be to go about adding the ability to search by name as described above?

### Edit

Adding my urls conf

```py
from .Secret.viewsets import SecretViewset

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'^api/secrets', SecretViewset, 'secrets')

# Later on, router gets imported and added on via `urlpatterns += router.urls`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using a simple APIView and a custom url path.

Code for the view:

```py
class SecretRetrieveView(rest_framework.views.APIView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        secrets = Secret.objects.filter(name__contains=kwargs['name'])
        return Response(SecretSerializer(secrets, many=True).data)
```

Code in your urls config: (Don't forget to import SecretRetrieveView!)

```py
custom_urlpatterns = [
    path('/api/secrets/name/<str:name>/', SecretRetrieveView.as_view(), name='secret-retrieve'),
]
```

Finally, Make sure your urls conf looks like this

```
urlpatterns += custom_urlpatterns
urlpatterns += router.urls
```

Answer (score 0):

in yor urls.py put */api/secrets/name/NAMEHERE/* before */api/secrets/ID/*

Comment: Added my url config to my original post.  I don't import them individually like that, only the entire viewset.  So I'm not sure if I can do that.